# UPDATE with oracle and php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

My data is not being commited with this code:

```
<?php
$itens = 3;
$nota_aux = '1212';
$nota_xml = '33412';
$campo_aux = 'aux1';
$campo_xml = 'xml1';

for ($i=3; $i <= $itens; $i++) {
    $conn = oci_connect ('aux', 'aux', 'localhost/aux');

    $query = "update mlf_auxnfitem SET {$campo_aux} = (select {$campo_xml} from mrlv_nfeimportacaoitem where seqnotafiscal = {$nota_xml} and seqnfitem = {$i})
     where seqauxnotafiscal = {$nota_aux} and seqauxnfitem = {$i};";

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $r = oci_execute($stid);

    echo $query;

    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);
}
```

What's wrong with the code above? I used this tutorial: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm?print=preview

[`oci_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) (suggested by aynber) shows

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Check for [oci_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) after your parse and execute to see if there's any database errors.

Comment: Your values are not quoted. You really ought to be using parameter binding. See the information on the [parse documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php).

Comment: did the trick! thanks!